# How to add custom block in tinyMce

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4, rte

I wanted to add custom formatting block for TinyMCE, I Was able to do it with below code.

```
style_formats: [
{title : 'Code', block : 'pre', classes : 'pre-code', exact: true},]
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vWRGEg
[image]

However, by adding this code, the only Code block is visible in format drop-down.
There were some default Option e.g

1. Headings
2. Inline
3. Block
4. Alignment

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jazqEv

Is it possible to add custom code block under the Block - > pre section?

[image]

Comment: You need to include the defaults you want in the array also

Comment: @charlietfl - Any example?

Comment: Look at the defaults in the documentation

Comment: @charlietfl - Could you please help? I couldn't find it. I have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to merge with existing use `style_formats_merge: true` per  [docs](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-formatting/#style_formats_merge)

Answer (score 2):

try this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Micio/pwakj28d/)

```
style_formats: [
    { title: 'Headers', items: [
      { title: 'test', block: 'h1' },
      { title: 'h2', block: 'h2' },
      { title: 'h3', block: 'h3' },
      { title: 'h4', block: 'h4' },
      { title: 'h5', block: 'h5' },
      { title: 'h6', block: 'h6' }
    ] },

    { title: 'Blocks', items: [
      { title: 'p', block: 'p' },
      { title: 'div', block: 'div' },
      { title: 'pre', block: 'pre' }
    ] },

    { title: 'Containers', items: [
      { title: 'section', block: 'section', wrapper: true, merge_siblings: false },
      { title: 'article', block: 'article', wrapper: true, merge_siblings: false },
      { title: 'blockquote', block: 'blockquote', wrapper: true },
      { title: 'hgroup', block: 'hgroup', wrapper: true },
      { title: 'aside', block: 'aside', wrapper: true },
      { title: 'figure', block: 'figure', wrapper: true }
    ] }
  ],
  visualblocks_default_state: true,
  end_container_on_empty_block: true
```

Comment: @LW001 he must rewrite the 'style_formats' of the plugin;
for example (third line): { title: 'test', block: 'h1' },
I added a new format called 'test' as subsection

Comment: thank You, I was able to customize RTE options, however, could you please tell me how can I include custom templates? e.g i click on template one it will include some html and place to write as well?